# OpenGL sometimes drawing tringle, sometimes just part of it

Tags: c++, opengl

I wrote a program in C++ and OpenGL. This shuold draw one black triangle. Quite often it draws the triangle in right way, but sometimes it looks incorrect.

This is the goal:
[image]

There are two of rare incorrect results:
[image]
[image]

The main function:

```
int main(void)
{
    // Initialise GLFW
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        return -1;
    }

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);

// Open a window and create its OpenGL context
window = glfwCreateWindow(700, 700, "Arkanoid", NULL, NULL);
if (window == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n");
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

// Initialize GLEW
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
    return -1;
}

// Dark blue background
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.8f, 0.0f);

programID = LoadShaders("TransformVertexShader.vertexshader", "ColorFragmentShader.fragmentshader");

vertexPosition_modelspaceID = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "vertexPosition_modelspace");
vertexColorID = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "vertexColor");

glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouseMove);

game = new Game();
game->vertexPosition_modelspaceID = vertexPosition_modelspaceID;
game->vertexColorID = vertexColorID;

game->prepareToDrawBoardBorderElement();

posXId = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "posX");
posYId = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "posY");

do {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(programID);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexPosition_modelspaceID);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexColorID);

    glUniform1f(posXId, 0.0f);
    glUniform1f(posYId, 0.0f); 
    game->drawBoardBorders();

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexPosition_modelspaceID);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexColorID);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
} while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS && glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);

glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glDeleteProgram(programID);

glfwTerminate();

return 0;
```

}

The Game.cpp file looks like this:

```
void Game::drawBoardBorders() 
{
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

void Game::prepareToDrawBoardBorderElement()
{   
std::cout << "prepareToDrawBoardBorderElement \n";

g_vertex_buffer_data[0] = -1.0f;
g_vertex_buffer_data[1] =  1.0f;
g_vertex_buffer_data[2] =  0.0f;

g_vertex_buffer_data[3] = -0.5f;
g_vertex_buffer_data[4] =  1.0f;
g_vertex_buffer_data[5] =  0.0f;

g_vertex_buffer_data[6] = -1.0f;
g_vertex_buffer_data[7] =  0.0f;
g_vertex_buffer_data[8] =  0.0f;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    g_color_buffer_data[i] = 0.0f;
}

glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    vertexPosition_modelspaceID, // The attribute we want to configure
    3,                  // size
    GL_FLOAT,           // type
    GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
    0,                  // stride
    (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );

glGenBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_color_buffer_data), g_color_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    vertexColorID,               // The attribute we want to configure
    3,                           // size
    GL_FLOAT,                    // type
    GL_FALSE,                    // normalized?
    0,                           // stride
    (void*)0                     // array buffer offset
    );
// All of the above information you only need to specify to openGL once, not every time you draw a frame!
}
```

Why sometimes I get something unexpected?
What should I do to make it works correctly?

Answer (score 4):

You initialize one element to few in g_color_buffer_data.

This code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
   g_color_buffer_data[i] = 0.0f;
}
```

initializes only the first 8 elements of the array, but drawing three corner points will require 9 color-floats since you are using 3 floats (rgb) by vertex.

Another hint: You are using modern OpenGL which is really good. Just note, that starting from OpenGL 3.3 Core Profile, using VertexArrayObjects is mandatory. See for example [this link (section Vertex Data)](http://retokoradi.com/2014/03/30/opengl-transition-to-core-profile/). This does not affect the problem discribed here, but should only be stated as additional information for future work.

Comment: That's true - I should make 9 iterations in this loop.

I don't understand second part: "Another maybe unrelated hint since you are using modern OpenGL: Starting from OpenGL 3.3 Core Profile drawing without having an active VAO is not allowed.". Could you explain it in simpler words?

Comment: I (hopefully) clarified what I meant. Has one more iteration solved your problem?

Comment: Sadly no. Sometimes I get only the blue window

Comment: @SzymonSkrzyński Is `g_color_buffer_data` defined with the right size?

Comment: Yes, g_color_buffer_data is ok. I don't know what I did, but when I add more elements to canvas everything started to work perfect!

Comment: @Simon, I'm having the same issue. What is 'canvas'? Where did you add more elements?